# What is the Product equivalent of Averaging?

Tags: analysis, average, data-analysis

if "Average" is the term for taking the sum of many values and multiplying by the inverse-count, what is the term for multiplying many values and raising to the inverse-count power?

so instead of the process of Averaging:
$$\left(\sum\limits_1^n N_i\right)\frac{1}{n}$$
I'm looking for the name of this process:
$$\left( \prod\limits_1^n N_i\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$

This may have already been asked, but I've been searching for about a half hour with no luck or idea on how to word the search. This is apparently a very difficult term to search for.

Comment: it's called geometric mean

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are calling "averaging" is usually called the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean).

The equivalent for products is called the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).

The two are famously related by the AM-GM inequality:

[$$\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n N_i}\leqslant\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n N_i.$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

There are other means, such as the Harmonic mean [$$\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{N_i}},$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean)
which is $\leqslant$ the geometric mean. These three together are known as the *Pythagorean means*.
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases) for a list of popular means.